# How to redirect download to new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a HTML tab with a image inside of it. I'm currently using the library `HTML2Canvas` to capture the `div` and download it. But the problem is when i click the `capture` button it straight away downloads the image.

What i'm trying to accomplish is that when i click the `capture` button it will open a new tab and download the image and then close the tab. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be highly appreciated thank you.

```js
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  });
}


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 8px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}

.test-panel {
  display: table;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #b7bcbe;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabwidth {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture">
    <div class="test-panel">
      <div class="tabwidth">
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">Pikachu</button>
        </div>

        <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
          <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/l2txqenox/Pikachu.png" width="300" height="300" crossorigin>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="match-button" onclick="sendData();">capture</button>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: _Why_ would you want that new tab? I personally find that effect rather annoying.

Comment: @CBroe For tracking purposes, when the user clicks the capture button i need it to redirect to another link and close it

Comment: Why, does this tracker not offer JS functions you can call to track specific events?

Comment: Plus, that’s not gonna work this way to begin with, I suppose. Your link already *has* a href - your actual file to download. Adding a target attribute to the link is not going to make it a different URL that could track anything.

Comment: @CBroe hmm do you have any suggestion on how i would accomplish this? after i click download i want another tab to open and close another URL after download.

Comment: You could start by answering my question about the tracker. Still not convinced this needs an additional window to open to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe using some google analytics stuff to track so when i need the user to redirect the user to a link to track number of downloads

Comment: Why? Google Analytics provides ways of tracking via JS function calls, no? So what do you think you need this additional “link” for?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target` attribute `blank` to the `a` element. It opens the link in a new tab.

```
<a id="test" href="#" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Try this solution with the `download` attribute, maybe that will work in some way?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code before initiating the click event. Hope this helps.

```
  $('#test').click(function(){
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
      });
```

Comment: google chrome seems to block popups for this method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anchor dynamically so to open it in new tab you need to give it target attribute as _blank.

```
$('#test').attr('target', '_blank');
```

add above line inside then function in your sendData function.

You will be good to go.